# How to adjust iframe width using an input on angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I am building a new feature that enables the users to resize an iframe using an input. I have an `iframe` which I'd like to adjust its width based on an `input type="number"`. I am thinking of doing it with a directive approach

```
@Component({
    selector: "demo-iframe",
    template: `
        <form>
          <input type="number" [customPx]="`test`">px
          <button type="submit">Adjust width</button>
        </form>
    `
})

export class DemoIframeCmp {
    @Input() public customPx: string;
    public ngOnInit () {
       if (this.customPx) {
          console.log('YES', this.customPx);
       } else {
          console.log('NOPE', this.customPx);
       }
    }
}
```

But then I see an error on the console that my input has no `customPx` attr. My questions are:

- Is `Directive` is a good approach?
- Is there a better approach for my feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, using Directive, in this case, is not a better solution, but you can do it this way in theory. Of course, you get such error in console, because native input element doesn't have 'customPx' attribute. You must write directive with the selector of 'customPx'.

In my opinion, there is a better and easier approach: you can use angular's two-way bindings. 
I've created a [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/GYHVNe/) for this. 
There are two variants to get the functionality you need.

The first, as I said, is to use two-way binding for instant iframe resizing (as-you-type, in other words):

Template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model.px">px
<iframe [width]="model.px"></iframe>
```

Component:

```
@Component(/*...*/)
class Blabla {
  model = {
    px: 10
  }
}
```

The second is to use classic form submission with prevention of default event behavior to resize iframe only after you submit a form:

Template:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit($event)">
  <input [(ngModel)]="model.px">px
</form>
<iframe [width]="px"></iframe>
```

Component:

```
 @Component(/*...*/)
 class Blabla {
   model = {
     px: 10
   }

   onSubmit(event: Event) {
     event.preventDefault()
     this.px = this.model.px
   }
 }
```